# Static Library needs to reference project configuration file

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I am creating a static library that references some #define configuration parameters in an external header file configuration.h

I have compiled the static library and installed it into another project which contains a configuration.h file.  However changing the parameters in that file has no effect.  It seems that the configuration.h is being compiled into the static library thereby rendering the parameters hard coded.

How do I get a static library to reference an external file?

Answer (score 1):

The header file containing `#define` preprocessor directives can only affect **compilation** of code. Since the static library is already compiled, it is not affected by preprocessor directives.

You should use runtime constructs, like `if` to change the way your static library behaves.

If your code was:

```
// configuration.h
#define USE_FLUX_CONDENSER 1

// static library
void advanceTime() {
    #if USE_FLUX_CONDENSER
        chargeFluxCondenser()
    #endif
}
```

It will become:

```
// configuration.h
extern BOOL g_useFluxCondenser;

// static library
BOOL g_useFluxCondenser;
void advanceTime() {
    if (g_useFluxCondenser) {
        chargeFluxCondenser()
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your initialization code you set `g_useFluxCondenser = YES`.

Comment: I am trying to apply your example to my situation, but I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing.  Let me provide another example to help us understand each other.
The popular mobile ad networks provide an iOS static library and public header files.  One of those header files has a few #define, which is used by the developer to set an 'appkey'.  This appkey is used to identify to the server the particular app the static library is being used in.
How would this situation work under the method you are proposing?

Comment: In this case the defined appkey will probably be used later on in the same header file to serve as an argument in some inline activation function or so. You have to look for places where the #define is used.

Comment: Yes the #define is used inside the static library.  The point is that if I change the appkey value in my project then the static library would use that updated value, ie the value is not compiled into the static library, but is changeable in my project.
I need to achieve this functionality.

Comment: As I said, if the #define is used in the static library and you do not recompile the static library, how should it know? Everything you #define is only used while compiling, not when linking.

Comment: yes, I understand the precompiler just does a find and replace for #define's.  I am reviewing the functionality of other static libraries, as I may have misinterpreted how they have implemented it.